# How to color a row in a datagrid if a checkbox is clicked?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a datagridview, and i fill it this way:

```
DataGridViewRow^ row = gcnew DataGridViewRow;

        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell^ CBox = gcnew DataGridViewCheckBox;//DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
        row->Cells->Add( CBox );
        CBox->Value = false;
        CBox->ReadOnly = false;

        DataGridViewTextBoxCell^ PName = gcnew DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        row->Cells->Add( PName );
        PName->Value = strPackageName;
        PName->ReadOnly = true;

        DataGridViewTextBoxCell^ AppV = gcnew DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        row->Cells->Add( AppV );
        AppV->Value = strAppVendor;
        AppV->ReadOnly = true;

        DataGridViewTextBoxCell^ AppN = gcnew DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        row->Cells->Add( AppN );
        AppN->Value = strAppName;
        AppN->ReadOnly = true;

dataGridView1->Rows->Add( row );
```

I want to do the following. If i click the checkbox, i want to change the rows color. Unfortunately i didn't find the corresponding event of the datagrid, because every event has some problem.
Could some tell me which event should i use, or how should i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work.

```
  if (CBox->Checked)
  {
      PName->BackColor = Color::Red;
      AppV->BackColor = Color::Red;
      AppN->BackColor = Color::Red;

  }
```

Comment: I know how to set the color, i just don't know which event to use. My problem is, that if i click on a checkbox, then the value changes, but the cell enters edit mode, and if i change the value again without changing the cell selection that it won't work anymore, unitl i change the cell selection